# Print characters behind the digits

Tags: command-line, bash

function/script, that for argument in format (alphas and digits) `afa5hgt3tt`, `errerew9ax66w`, prints characters behind the digits many times as value of digit, e.g.

```
hgthgthgthgthgttttttt

axaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxwwwwwww...
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
func () {
  repeats=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)\([0-9]*\)\([A-Za-z]*\)\([0-9]*\)\([A-Za-z]*\)/\2/g')
  for (( i = 0; i < $repeats; i++ )); do
    echo $1 | sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)\([0-9]*\)\([A-Za-z]*\)\([0-9]*\)\([A-Za-z]*\)/\3/g' | tr -d "\n"
  done
  echo -e "\n"
}
func afa5hgt3tt
func errerew9ax66w
```

My function fails to print the last characters behind the digit. that is the ttttt and wwww.

Comment: Do not repost questions.

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl`(Thx [@terdon](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47392))

```
perl -pe 's/(.)(\d+)+/$1 x $2/eg'
```

Or as function

```
func () {
  perl -pe 's/(.)(\d+)+/$1 x $2/eg' <<< "$1"
}
```

---

*Example*

```
% perl -pe 's/(.)(\d+)+/$1 x $2/eg' <<< "afa5hgt66tt"
afaaaaahgtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

% perl -pe 's/(.)(\d+)+/$1 x $2/eg' <<< "errerew9ax66w"
errerewwwwwwwwwaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw

% perl -pe 's/(.)(\d+)+/$1 x $2/eg' <<< "afa5hgt3tt"   
afaaaaahgttttt
```

Comment: how about on bash and not perl ? thanks! like a remodification of my script..

Comment: @MartinYeboah no worries, give me an upvoted ;) and why not perl in a bash script?